# How to store API data in component state and display it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

So I feel like there is something small here that im missing, but don't really know what.

```
constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      developers: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('API').then(features => {
      return features.json();
    }).then(data => {
      let developers = data.features.map((info) => {
        let developer_info = info.properties.name
        return(
        <div key={info.id}>
        {info.properties.name}
        {info.properties.skills}
        </div>
          )
      })
      this.setState({ developers: developers});
      console.log("state", this.state.developers)
      console.log(this.props)
    })

  }
```

I would ideally like to call

this.state.developers.name
or this.state.developers.skills

as i need this information, but currently i am only able to save one property in the this.state or i can call out each thing. as i have done above, but its not useful, bc i can't put the info where i need it.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is missing ..

Comment: sorry it uploaded before i was ready, .. all finished now

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You can save multiple properties on `this.state` if you like. Note that [`setState` is **asynchronous**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), though, so in the code above, if you're expecting to see the developers on `this.state` immediately after `this.setState({developers: developers})`, you won't. That's fine, just write your `render` and it'll get called at the relevant time.

Comment: You shouldn't store your react elements in the `state`!, store the `developers` data instead, and create your react elements later when needed.

Comment: honestly, thats what im trying to do.. but im new to react, and its just getting away from me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, in `state` you only want to store "serialisable" data. In general this means you should not store functions or recursive data structures.

A good way to check if your data is serialisable is to think if you could (or attempt to) use `JSON.stringify()` on it.

What you are storing here is almost certainly not serialisable, as you are storing to state complete React elements. A React element is the thing that is returned when you do `<Component />` (which is the same as `React.createElement(Component, ...)`.

So, in your case, what you should do is

```
let developers = data.features.map((info) => {
    const developer_info = {
        name: info.properties.name,
        skills: info.properties.skills
    }
    return developer_info;
});

this.setState({ developers: developers});
```

So now you would have an array of plain Javascript objects in your state.

Comment: thanks, . i think im almost there. in the console this.state, gives me all the developers name and skill, but in this case i dont know how to get this printed on the page, .. do i need to make another map, or loop to just print a simple list of all the developers and their skills.. this.state.name does not work also this.state.developers.name also does not yield results

Comment: Try returning this in your render function: `return this.state.developers.map((dev) => <div key={dev.name}>{dev.name}</div>)` and let us know if it displays anything. It should.

Comment: thanks this works !

Comment: Glad I could help you! By the way, if you have a developer id available, add it as a field in the `developer_info` and use it as a key when you render the data, instead of using `name` as I did in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Access the updated state in callback of `setState`:

```
this.setState({ developers }, () => console.log("state", this.state.developers));
```

You should also store the data in state instead of the component view code (the html tags).
Access `this.state.developers`'s properties in the component view code instead.

Comment: I dont know what to do in the section  inside of my map ,, like what to put in the return, like currently.. the only children props are name... but there is alot more information i would like to have access to

Comment: add your current `render` function.